# ThreadPoolExecutor that favors new threads over queuing from Open Source

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I have been working with ThreadPoolExecutor and Spring and it's ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.  As of JDK 11 there's no built in ThreadPoolExecutor and queue that favors favors new threads over queuing.  As well, I can't find any Open Source project that provides this.

What I want is a ThreadPoolExecutor and Queue that will create new threads as new Runnables are submitted and once max threads is reached to queue.

I don't want to set coreThreads == maxThreads as I have 100 threads.  Plus I don't want to have all my core threads to setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut as I want a few ready to respond whan a Runnable is submitted.

Yes I can use SynchronousQueue but this rejects the Runnable when we hit the max threads and doesn't queue.  The LinkedTransferQueue kind of works but needs to be modified.

The only solution I have found is:

```
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
            BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedTransferQueue<Runnable>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                @Override
                public boolean offer(Runnable e) {
                    return tryTransfer(e);
                }
            };
            return queue;
        }
    };

    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            //if no threads avaiable then put in the queue
            try {
                executor.getQueue().put(r);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    });
```

This works exactly as I want, but seems to be a hack/workaround.

I was wondering if Apache, Google, or anywhere this library exists.  I find the solution to be a work around and not "hardened" by the community.

Thanks

Comment: this is _exactly_ what we do across various projects. good question, but I doubt there is something...

Comment: I had a really hard time parsing this question at first (nothing wrong with the question, just a complicated issue). If only you could have additional designated "hard core" threads that would be exempt from timeout, then you could get away with the `core == max` and `coreThreadTimeout` to get the logic (if my parsing is correct).

Comment: @Kayaman correct.  I find the lack of this kind of support frustrating.  Core threads that die, starting "all" threads upon start up, and threads that don't start due to having a queue.  I understand the need to be resource conscience and considerate, but if I have resources just use them and don't queue.